# ReactJs - Converting raw HTML with nested React Component into JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, haml, jsx

I've recently been trying to define my rendered JSX in a separate file, namely with HAML and then use a loader with Webpack to convert the HAML to usable JSX. I do this by first converting the HAML to HTML with the haml-haml-loader module and then use the html-to-react module to finish the job. However, I've found that there are many ways to do this, not just the one outlined here.
This works well when the HAML is pure HAML, such as

```
.wrapper
    %p Hello World
```

However, the beauty of React JSX is that you can nest tags of other React components within the JSX provided to the render function. So, of course I would like to define that functionality through HAML:

```
.wrapper
    %Greeting/
```

which, when run through Webpack returns the following HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <Greeting>
</div>
```

as a string. Looks good, right? However, when using either the dangerouslySetInnerHtml or the html-to-react npm package (as well as many other modules), the converted JSX becomes:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <greeting></greeting>
</div>
```

which is not the intended JSX. 
Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

To render HAML inside JSX, you can use https://github.com/dingbat/haml-jsx-loader library.
It's a Webpack loader. 
Then you can have something like

```
render() {
  return (~
    .wrapper
      <Greetings />
  ~);
}
```

Cool, isn't it?

If you don't use Webpack, there are other libraries (mostly implementing Jade inside JSX).